# Query about Creating a Socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

Hi I am new to Programming and have started learning socket programming in Python. I was going through some of the documentation of creating a socket in Python, and found this basic simple code:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind("127.0.0.1",5001)
```

I am a bit confused about the line `sock = socket.socket()`, wherein we are creating the socket.

To the best of my knowledge, when we are importing "`socket`", that `socket` is a class, which contains a numbers of variables and methods. Some of these methods are `bind(),connect(),send()`... etc.

In order to access these methods I need to create an object of the socket class. Now the syntax to create to an object of a socket class would be:

```
sock = socket()
```

so that I can access the `bind()` method of the class through `sock.bind()`, which is my last line of code is doing.

But then why is the syntax of creating syntax is

```
sock = socket.socket() and not sock = socket()
```

Would appreciate if any of you could help me on this.

Comment: the class socket is in a module also called socket. Thus socket.socket

Comment: Hey Sam doesn't one module also represent a class or does a module contain multiple classes.

Comment: As Sam stated, socket is the module. It's just called "socket". It could be called "networking", and then you would be calling `sock = networking.socket()`. 'socket' isn't just one class called socket. It has a bunch of other methods in it.

Comment: On the related topic of import, see http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket), you'll see that the proper call is `socket.socket()`.

To find out what this is, use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function on it:

```
In [1]: import socket

In [2]: type(socket.socket)
Out[2]: type
```

This indicates that *socket*.**socket** is a **class** in a *module*.

But if you do

```
from socket import socket
```

you could use

```
sock = socket()
```

instead.

---

As an aside, the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that the names of classes should follow the *CapWords* convention.

So it *should* probably have been named `socket.Socket`.

It could be the name `socket.socket` predates the style guide, or that it mimics the BSD function name that it wraps.
In any case, it given how much existing code there is, I guess it will probably never be changed.

Comment: Thanks Roland. It was very helpful